# Uniswap V1 createExchange() return value in Remix not captured

Tags: solidity, remix, remix-tests

I'm testing the following Uniswap V1 Factory contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Exchange.sol";

contract Factory {
    mapping(address => address) public tokenToExchange;

    function createExchange(address _tokenAddress) public returns(address) {
        require(_tokenAddress != address(0), "incorrect address");
        require(tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress] == address(0), "exchange already exists");

        Exchange exchange = new Exchange(_tokenAddress);
        tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress] = address(exchange);

        return address(exchange);
    }

    function getExchange(address _tokenAddress) public view returns (address) {
        return tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress];
    }
}
```

With the following test:

```
it("create exchanges", async () => {
            const exchangeAAddress = await factory.createExchange(tokenA.address);
            const exchangeBAddress = await factory.createExchange(tokenB.address);

            expect(await factory.getExchange(tokenA.address)).to.equal(exchangeAAddress);
            expect(await factory.getExchange(tokenB.address)).to.equal(exchangeBAddress);
        });
```

Before that test of course tokenA, tokenB and factory are successfully deployed.

The expect() fails with the following error:

```
create exchanges (326 ms)
     - Expected: [object Object]
     + Received: 0x79AbD41F8014BB03512b426f35cd5d4d6B04246c
     Message: expected '0x79AbD41F8014BB03512b426f35cd5d4d6B0…' to equal { …(17) }
```

Which means that the exchangeAAddress constant contains an object rather than an address. This is not expected as the createExchange() returns an address as per the solidity code above.

I tried to put the below line inside the above test to see what's inside the exchangeAAdress:

```
console.log("address A: " + exchangeAAddress.toString());
console.log("address A again: " + await factory.getExchange(tokenA.address));
```

but it doesn't work, I get the following output:

```
address A: [object Object]
address A again: 0xcf49E9E66a280f347CFf4C958FFFbEa581937FED
```

So the exchange was created successfully, its address was written into the contract state and it could be obtained through getExchange()

Now when I test it through the GUI manually, I get the following:

[image]

You can see that the exchange was created successfully again as you see the '0:
address: 0x9eE3254BFdA2079B330586DF99ee8f09682747b9' output under the getExchange() button., however you don't see any output below the createExchange orange "transact" button, which in my opinion should be there also as createExchange() return the address.

On the other hand in the console when I look into the two transactions (one from createExchange() second from getExchange() - ok not really a transaction), I see that both have the same output:

```
{
    "0": "address: 0x9eE3254BFdA2079B330586DF99ee8f09682747b9"
}
```

That looks like a Remix bug to me, but... Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like this issue is happening for each non-view and non-pure functions.